# Displaying Buttons Dependant on Drop-down Choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

I'm using setInterval in JS to get the selection of a drop down menu in a form. And based on the selection, I want to display 1 purchase button or another one.

My problem is the

Here is my JF

```
setInterval (function() {
    var auto_renew = $('#auto_renew').val();

    if (auto_renew == 1) {
        $'#subscription_purchase').css('display', 'none');
        $('#normal_purchase').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $'#subscription_purchase').css('display', 'none');
        $('#normal_purchase').css('display', 'inline');
    }
}, 0)
```

and here's my HTML

```
<div id="subscription_purchase" style="display:none;">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="hiddentotal2" value="5.00">
  ......
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE SUB" />

</div>

<div id="normal_purchase" style="display:none;">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="hiddentotal2"  value="1">
  ...... 
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE NORM" />

</div>
```

There must be a smarter way to do this...

Comment: The smartest way to do this is server side. I had the same problem, but since I was using a CMS with no access to server side code had to do this client side

Comment: @ScottyDoesKnow how would you do it server side? WIth PHP? I'm not sure I would know how

Comment: @ScottyDoesKnow like I pass all my variables to a temp.php who then decides where to send it to paypal? Something like that ?

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval`, is there any specific reason. Can't you use `onchange` event of the dropdown?

Comment: @Aruna I could... would that fix my problem?

Comment: Yes that could fix the problem. You can post the `dropdown` code and I can place a sample for this if you want.

Comment: @Aruna ok, if you can show me an example, that would be great. thx

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#auto_renew').on('change', function(){
     var selected = $(this).val();
     var subscriptionElm = $('#subscription_purchase');
     var normalElm = $('#normal_purchase');
    
     switch (selected) {
         case '1':
            subscriptionElm.show();
            normalElm.hide();
            break;
         case '0':
            subscriptionElm.hide();
            normalElm.show();
            break;
         default:
            subscriptionElm.hide();
            normalElm.hide();
            break;
     }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="auto_renew">
  <option value="-1"></option>
  <option value="1">Subscription Purchase</option>
  <option value="0">Normal Purchase</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div id="subscription_purchase" style="display:none;">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="hiddentotal2" value="5.00">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE SUB" />

</div>

<div id="normal_purchase" style="display:none;">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="hiddentotal2"  value="1">
 
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE NORM" />

</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work.  Sure, the different purchase button show or hide, but when I submit to paypal, it still doens't work. I think it's because of the hidden type input of the other buttons.

Comment: the different paypal value like :  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"> are not the same in each button, so that's why it's not working.

Comment: you mean use the JS to update the "cmd" value... didn't think of that. let me try

Comment: there are more than 1 and some of them have to be remove and replace.  Exmaple

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
changed for :
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

but some like this:
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
have to be removed and changed for this:

<input type="hidden" name="a3" id="hiddentotal2" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">